# ReferenceError: window is not defined when using webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I'm getting a `window not defined` error when using webpack to compile my project and I can't seem to understand why. I've tried adding different loaders and setting global object to be `this`, but still can't seem to get it working.

#### Error

```
[nodemon] starting `node build/bundle.js`
^[[A/Users/schachte/Desktop/node_modules/golden-layout/dist/goldenlayout.js:5339
} );})(window.$);
       ^

ReferenceError: window is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/schachte/Desktop/node_modules/golden-layout/dist/goldenlayout.js:5339:8)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/schachte/Desktop/build/bundle.js:1:6416)
    at r (/Users/schachte/Desktop/build/bundle.js:1:172)
```

#### Webpack Config

```
const path = require("path");
const merge = require("webpack-merge");
const baseConfg = require("./webpack.base.js");
const webpackNodeExternals = require("webpack-node-externals");

const config = {
  // Inform webpack that we are building a bundle for node.js
  // rather than for the browser
  target: "node",

  // Tell webpack the root file of our
  // server application
  entry: [
    nodeResolve("babel-polyfill"),
    nodeResolve("whatwg-fetch"),
    "./src/server/index.js"
  ],

  // Tell webpack where to put the output file that is generate
  output: {
    filename: "bundle.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "build")
  },
  externals: [webpackNodeExternals()]
};

module.exports = merge(baseConfg, config);
```

Comment: why would node have "window" ?

Comment: I'm not saying it should, just wondering what the solution is to help get around the issue.

Comment: Im doing serverside rendering

Comment: Are you importing or defining jquery somewhere? webpack shouldn't be injecting `window.$` by itself.

Comment: The "simple" answer to your question is to set `output.globalObject` to `"global"` in your webpack configs, but I don't think that will fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you use webpack to bundle your code to use it in browser. From your comment to another answer you mentioned plus from you question we can see `target: "node"` therefore this code will run on a server. It looks like somewhere in your code you rely on having jquery on the window object. Nodejs does not have a window object so the code fails. To make it work you need to either bundle jquery with your code by importing it in your source code like `import $ from 'jquery'` so it will get bundled properly.